# Using RxJS fromEvent and @ViewChild vs keyup event and RxJS Subject for input field value changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a simple component that performs a search using the values typed into a Search box. I found two different ways to code this and they both work.

Method 1 uses `fromEvent` from RxJS and sets up an observable to capture input field value changes using the `@ViewChild` reference to the input element.

Method 2 captures the input field value changes using the `keyup` event and feeds the new value to an RxJS `Subject`.

Most of the examples I found on Stackoverflow and other sites use @ViewChild for this type of scenario. Is there any reason to use one method over the other or is it a matter of personal choice?

#### METHOD 1

app.component.html

```
<input type="text" #search placeholder="Search" />
<li *ngFor="let state of states$ | async">
  {{ state.text }}
</li>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('search', { static: true }) search: ElementRef;
  states$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.states$ = fromEvent(this.search.nativeElement, 'input').pipe(
      map((event: any) => event.target.value),
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((searchText: string) => this.dataService.getData(searchText))
    );
  }
}
```

#### METHOD 2

app.component.html

```
<input
  type="text"
  (keyup)="searchStringChange(getValue($event))"
  placeholder="Search"
/>
<li *ngFor="let state of states$ | async">
  {{ state.text }}
</li>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  states$: Observable<any[]>;
  private searchText$ = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.states$ = this.searchText$.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap({ next: (searchText: string) => console.log(searchText) }),
      switchMap((searchText: string) => this.dataService.getData(searchText))
    );
  }

  searchStringChange(userInput: string) {
    this.searchText$.next(userInput);
  }

  getValue(event: Event): string {
    return (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to avoid @ViewChild whenever possible. The reason is because the code is simpler when the component does not have to deal with template concerns. When you introduce template concerns, you need to worry about whether or not the targeted element is currently in the DOM (*it could be hidden by ngIf*) and you need to worry about accessing it in the proper angular lifecycle hook.

When using the "subject approach", the component only need be concerned with the data and the template can simply push the data based on the relative events.

Note, in your "Method 2" it's not necessary to use `ngOnInit`, you can simply initialize your observable "on the class":

```js
export class AppComponent {

  private searchText$ = new Subject<string>();

  states$: Observable<any[]> = this.searchText$.pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap(searchText => console.log(searchText)),
    switchMap(searchText => this.dataService.getData(searchText))
  ); 

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  searchStringChange(userInput: string) {
    this.searchText$.next(userInput);
  }

  getValue(event: Event): string {
    return (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  }
}
```

---

There is also a third way to handle this, since you're dealing with a form input.  You can use Angular's Reactive Forms.  The FormControl object provides a convenient `valueChanges` observable, which emits whenever the input value changes:

```js
export class AppComponent {

  searchText = new FormControl<string>('');

  states$ = this.searchText.valueChanges.pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap(searchText => console.log(searchText)),
    switchMap(searchText => this.dataService.getData(searchText))
  ); 

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

}
```

```html
<input type="text" [formControl]="searchText" placeholder="Search" />

<li *ngFor="let state of states$ | async">
  {{ state.text }}
</li>
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-77938325-reactive-forms?file=src%2Fmain.ts) demo.